# React won`t render array map function

Tags: reactjs

Hello I am new with new with React js. We have to create a project for counting points for teams, there are 4 teams in total. Every team has 5 children in it. Now I created an array to have 5 counts with id. The 5 counters are meant for the children. You should be able to add points for every child. So it is possible to update it by id with buttons. I`m using React in laravel. Here is the code:

```
export default class Gryffindor extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            counters: []
        };
        this.fetchCounter = this.fetchCounter.bind(this);
    }

    fetchCounter(e) {
        const counters = [
            { id: 1, amount: 0 },
            { id: 2, amount: 0 },
            { id: 3, amount: 0 },
            { id: 4, amount: 0 },
            { id: 5, amount: 0 }
        ];
        this.setState({ counters });
    }


    render() {
        return <CounterBody counters={this.state.counters} />;
    }
}

const CounterBody = ({ counters }) => (
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Test</th>
                <th>Test</th>
                <th>Test</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            {counters.map(counter => (
                <tr key={counter.id}>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>{counter.amount}</td>
                    <td></td>
                </tr>
            ))}
        </tbody>
    </table>
);

if (document.getElementById("Gryffindor")) {
    ReactDOM.render(<Gryffindor />, document.getElementById("Gryffindor"));
}
```

I have no idea why it is not showing up. Can someone help me?

Comment: You are never calling `fetchCounter`. You could try `componentDidMount() { this.fetchCounter(); }`

Comment: I believe `fetchCounter ` is not called anywhere in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are never calling `fetchCounter`. You could call it inside `componentDidMount`.

```js
class Gryffindor extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      counters: []
    };
    this.fetchCounter = this.fetchCounter.bind(this);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.fetchCounter();
  }

  fetchCounter() {
    const counters = [
      { id: 1, amount: 0 },
      { id: 2, amount: 0 },
      { id: 3, amount: 0 },
      { id: 4, amount: 0 },
      { id: 5, amount: 0 }
    ];
    this.setState({ counters });
  }

  render() {
    return <CounterBody counters={this.state.counters} />;
  }
}

const CounterBody = ({ counters }) => (
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Test</th>
        <th>Test</th>
        <th>Test</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {counters.map(counter => (
        <tr key={counter.id}>
          <td />
          <td>{counter.amount}</td>
          <td />
        </tr>
      ))}
    </tbody>
  </table>
);

ReactDOM.render(<Gryffindor />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```